# 301 redirection code in .htaccess to remove directory from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have tried alot to redirect url like

```
http://flexsin.org/lab/wordpress/interiorfoliage/product/cylinder/
```

to

```
http://flexsin.org/lab/wordpress/interiorfoliage/cylinder/
```

For this I am using this code

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ http://flexsin.org/lab/wordpress/interiorfoliage/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

but it's not working for me. i want's to remove product from url and all url as it is.

so plz suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: Where are you putting the above rule? Is mode-rewrite enabled? Is there a `RewriteEngine On` statement?

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? is it inside root or a subfolder?

Comment: Do you have this rule in `/lab/wordpress/interiorfoliage/.htaccess`?